# Union type using optional properties

Tags: typescript, types

I want to get a union of several types using optional properties instead property erasing. I wrote next code:

```
type A = { a: string, s: number };
type B = { b: string, s: number };
type C = { c: string, s: number };

type T_OR = A | B | C; // s
type T_AND = A & B & C; // a, b, c, s
type Result = Partial<T_AND> & T_OR; // a, b, c, s
```

I expect that Result type will contain `// a?, b?, c?, s` fields, but Typescript uses *Distributive conditional types* and transform `Result` to `(Partial<T_AND> & A) | (Partial<T_AND> & B) | (Partial<T_AND> & C)`.

How can I prevent this behavior and get expected result?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your issue does not stem from distribution of conditional type, but rather the distributive of union and intersection types. For typescript `(A | B) & C` is equal to `(A | C) & (B | C)`

The result is not what you expect it to be also because if you have an optional property intersected with a non optional one the result will be an mandatory property.

You can get the result you want by using `Pick` to pick the appropriate keys from `T_OR`, namely only the ones that are publicly visible on the union:

```
type A = { a: string, s: number };
type B = { b: string, s: number };
type C = { c: string, s: number };

type T_OR = A | B | C; // s
type T_AND = A & B & C; // a, b, c, s
type Result = Partial<T_AND> & Pick<T_OR, keyof T_OR>; // a?, b?, c?, s
```

Comment: Can you suggest how can I save optionality of s field? Because Pick removes it.

Comment: @Dem0n13 that is strange ... I would have expected optionality to be preserved, pick should do that .. I will try to find a around ..

Comment: @Dem0n13 this seems to do the job : `type Result = Partial<T_AND> & (T_OR extends infer T ? T extends any ? Pick<T, keyof T_OR>: never: never); ` (although intelisense does not show the property as optional, it is optional .. )

Answer (score 0):

Alternative way:

```
type A = { a: string, s: number };
type B = { b: string, s: number };
type C = { c: string, s: number };

type D = { s : number }; // <-- Declare an new type `D`

type T_OR = A | B | C; 

type Result = Partial<T_OR> & D; // a?, b?, c?, s
```

As a matter of fact, when using `Partial`, changing *union* type to *intersection* type would produce the same result:

```
type T_AND = A & B & C; 

type Result = Partial<T_AND> & D; // a?, b?, c?, s
```

Aside:

**It is important to understand Union (`|`) and Intersection (`&`) operators in TypeScript applies to the values, not to the properties.**

Think of types as Sets of values.

Any values which conforms to Union type, `T_OR`, can either have set of values for type `A` or `B` or `C` or any combination of `A or B or C`:

```
const first: T_OR = {
  s: 1,
  a: 'first'
}; // Ok


const second: T_OR = {
 s: 2,
 a: 'second'
}; // Ok


const third: T_OR = {
 s: 3,
 c: 'third'
} // Ok

const fourth: T_OR = {
 s: 1,
 a: 'first',
 b: 'second'
}; // Ok

const fifth: T_OR = {
 s: 4,
 b: 'second',
 c: 'third'
};

const seventh: T_OR = {
 s: 4,
 a: 'first',
 c: 'third'
};

const eighth: T_OR = {
 s: 4,
 a: 'second',
 c: 'third',
 b: 'second'
};
```

Whereas, for Intersection of type more constraint is added to the value.
Only the following holds true:

```
const val: T_AND = {
  s: 99,
  a: 'second',
  c: 'third',
  b: 'second' 
};
```